# Text formatting with different wrappers

Tags: formatting, text

Formatting text in *Mathematica* should be a punishment for serious crimes.

I've face another frustrating feature, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
tekst = StringJoin @@ Array["tekst " &, 15]; 

Composition[
   Grid[{{#, Graphics[Inset@#]}}, Frame -> All] &,  
   Panel[#, ImageSize -> {150, 100}] &,
   Style[#, LineIndent -> 0] &
           ][tekst]
```

[image]

Those texts should look the same imo. The only difference is that the one in `Graphics` is not formatted as it should be.

---

`Boxes` look well and I don't know what causes that:

```
...
PanelBox[
 StyleBox["\<\"tekst tekst ... tekst \"\>", StripOnInput->False, LineIndent->0],
  ImageSize->{150, 100}], 
GraphicsBox[InsetBox[
PanelBox[
  StyleBox["\<\"tekst ... tekst \"\>", StripOnInput->False, LineIndent->0],
...
```

I was trying to set `FormatType` for `Inset`or `BaseStyle` for `Graphics` or `ParagraphIndent -> 0`. But with no avail :/.

Help me please :P

Comment: For me [they look the same](http://i.imgur.com/n0lAVWh.png), but a bit uglier than yours.  v8.0.4 linux

Comment: Try adding `TextAlignment -> Left` to the `Style`. I think the default for graphics is to centre text.

Comment: @SimonWoods I don't know how I've missed that. I suppose I was shocked and in rage of trying all those options on all levels I forgot it somehow :) Thanks

Comment: It's easy to miss I think, because the text is centre aligned within itself, but the text block itself is not centred in the panel. It makes it look like an indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Center` is the default alignment for text in Graphics, so

```
Composition[
  Grid[{{#, Graphics[Inset@#]}}, Frame -> All] &, 
  Panel[#, ImageSize -> {150, 100}] &,
  Style[#, LineIndent -> 0, TextAlignment -> Left] &][tekst]
```

will solve your problem.

[image: tekst.png]